# How do you use a variable in the footer of a VF page?

Tags: dynamic-visualforce

In the code below, I want to include the account name in the left footer dynamically.  If I have {!account.name} in the left footer, nothing displays there.  If I do not include {!account.name} I see the other text there.  How can I include a dynamic value from the controller in the footer?

```
@page { 
            @bottom-right { 
                content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); 
                font-size: 8pt; 
                color: #838383;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            } 
            @bottom-left { 
                content: "Proprietary and Confidential {!account.name}";
                font-weight: lighter; 
                font-size: 8pt; 
                color: #838383;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            } 
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this CSS part of VF page, and is it inside of the apex:form tag?

Comment: CSS is in the <style> part of the <header>.  This is a pdf, so no form tag.

Answer (score 1):

If your account name has any special characters aside from A-Z and 0-9, it may not render correctly. Use HTMLENCODE to make sure this doesn't happen:

```
content: "Proprietary and Confidential {!HTMLENCODE(account.name)}";
```

Comment: I ended up doing this in a <div>.  I am now trying to add a little space below the footer.  Neither changing the padding or margin, or <br/>'s have any effect.  How can add a little space between the footer and the bottom of the page?

Comment: @Jimhyland I'm not sure you can do this, actually. Have you tried finding a Code Pen example?

Comment: I was able to do this using the margin-bottom on the @page.

Comment: What is Code Pen?

Comment: @Jimhyland [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/) is a site where people build example HTML, CSS, and JS, then share it with the world. I usually go there to find specific snippets for something I'm trying to do but can't puzzle out.

Comment: Thanks for the info.